# my website is only occupying a fraction of my mobile browser screen in android sony xperia

Tags: responsive-design, web

this is its code it is only occupying 1/3rd of the browser page when seen through android chrome browser,Xperia z1 
please someone suggest some changes

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <style type="text/css" >
*{
    margin:0;
}



html { 
  background: url('Startupal coming soon4.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    img src="Startupal coming soon4.jpg" {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding; 0;}
}


}

</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>



</html>
```

this is the whole code,it works fine on pc but not on the cell phone

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript script tag or file and update the width and height of the html body element each time the page is resized.

I usually use window.innerWidth and innerHeight because it is cross compatible and seems reliable.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
function onResize(){
    document.body.width = window.innerWidth;
    document.body.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```